# JavaScript click event stops working when adding another click event listener

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, onclicklistener

The first click event works well while removing the second event listener but not when the second event is present. I cannot figure out why it is not working.

HTML

```
   <i class="fas fa-user-circle user-icon"></i>
       <div class="user-dropdown-container">
           <li>
              <p>My profile</p>
              <p>Logout</p>
           </li>
        </div>
```

JS

```
var dropdown = document.querySelector('.user-dropdown-container');

document.querySelector('.user-icon').addEventListener('click', () => {
  dropdown.classList.toggle('active');
});

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('user-dropdown-container')) {
    dropdown.classList.remove('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: I think it's because you are adding the event listener over the document, so if you click at any point of the document it will only work the second listener.

Comment: Can you let us know what you are trying? The second event listener will be a lot of times, since you are adding on document, and it will remove the class everytime, except the on time the event reaches in the dropDownContainer you have mentioned.